# Magento 2.4 exclude categories in the catalog product search

Tags: category, catalog, catalogsearch, elasticsearch, search-result

I have to exclude some categories from the product search, I have tried many ways but I can't exclude specific categories, I know that a product can be set not to appear in the search result, but I would like to know if it is possible create Same for categories.
Does anyone know if it's possible?
Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to exclude specific categories from a product search. The exact method for achieving this depends on the specific platform or system you are using for your product search. However, here are a few general approaches that can be applied:

1.**Filter by category:** Most product search systems allow you to filter search results based on various criteria, including category. You can specify the categories you want to exclude from the search results by using category filters. This will ensure that products belonging to those excluded categories are not displayed in the search results.

2.**Customized search algorithm:** If you have more advanced control over the search functionality, you can modify the search algorithm to exclude specific categories. This might involve adjusting the relevance scoring or ranking factors to prioritize or penalize certain categories.

3.**Tagging or labeling:** Another approach is to assign tags or labels to products and categories. You can then modify the search system to exclude specific tags or labels from appearing in the search results. This method provides more flexibility as you can tag products or categories based on specific attributes or characteristics.

4.**Manual exclusion:** If the number of categories you want to exclude is small and doesn't change frequently, you can manually exclude them from the search results. This can be done by maintaining a list of excluded categories and implementing a filtering mechanism to remove them from the search results.

It's important to note that the implementation details may vary depending on the platform or system you are using. If you are using a specific e-commerce platform or search framework, it's recommended to consult the documentation or reach out to their support team for guidance on how to exclude categories from the product search.

```
        *HOPE YOU IT CAN USEFUL TO YOU*
```

Comment: Do you know how I could modify the search algorithm to exclude categories?
Please help me.